# Fatal error: Assignments can only happen to writable values in C:\xampp\htdocs\dogs\application\controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I use a local XAMPP server.

PHP version 7.2.13
CodeIgniter 3.1.10

When I try to call the page posts, I get this **error message**:

```
Fatal error: Assignments can only happen to writable values in C:\xampp\htdocs\dogs\application\controllers\Posts.php on line 16

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Compile Error
Message: Assignments can only happen to writable values
Filename: controllers/Posts.php
Line Number: 16
Backtrace:
```

In  Sublime line Number 16 corresponds to:

```
$data = ['title'] = 'Latest Posts';
```

**My controller file Post.php:**

```php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Posts extends My_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('Post_model');

    $data = ['title'] = 'Latest Posts';

    $data = ['posts'] = $this->Post_model->get_posts();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

**My view file index.php:**

```
 <h2><?= $title ?></h2>
```

Comment: Change `$data = ['title'] = '...'` to `$data['title'] = '...'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error when trying to view PHP data as JSON with XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583172/fatal-error-when-trying-to-view-php-data-as-json-with-xampp)

Comment: declare your `$data` variable as `array()` first before assigning values like `$data['title];`

Comment: Thank you @makeful. It works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$data['title'] = 'Latest Posts';

$data['posts'] = $this->Post_model->get_posts();
```

Answer (score 0):

$data['user']=$this->Post_model->get_posts();
$data['user1']=$this->Post_model->get_id();
if we will send data's like this to an array then it will work.

Comment: please edit your answer and change the format for more readability

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass two arrays into an array then first you have to get two arrays.
like'
$result1=$this->model_name->get_data1();
$result2=$this->model_name->get_data2();
then,

```
  $data=array();
  $data['user']=$result1;
  $data['user1']=$result2;
```

like we can pass two array into an array
and also we can access in view pages usint variable '$user' and '$user1'

Answer (score 0):

```
class Click_image extends CI_Controller
{

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Click_image_model');
        $result=$this->Click_image_model->get_data();
        $array=array();
        $array=json_decode(json_encode($result),true);
        
        $data['user']=$array;
        $this->load->view('Click_image',$data);
    }


    function get_gallery_img($id)
    {
        

        $this->load->model('Click_image_model');
        $result1=$this->Click_image_model->get_name_of_gallery_id_person($id); 
        $data=array();
        $res=$result1[0]['name'];
        $res1=$result1[0]['profile_img'];
        $res3=$result1[0]['category'];
        $result=$this->Click_image_model->get_all_gallery_image($id);
        $cat_id=$this->Click_image_model->get_category_id($res3);
        print_r ($cat_id);
        die();
        $data=array();
        $data['user']=$result;
        $data['user1']=$res;
        $data['user2']=$res1;
        $this->load->view('Gallery_Images',$data);

    }
}
```